# How can we hide a particular column in table dynamically based on the value of check box in IBM BPM coach?

Tags: business-process-management, ibm-bpm, brazos

In Coach how to hide the column in a brazos tabel control based on check box value check.
when ever check box click in that time i need to show particular column in a tabel, other wise it should be hide.

we are using IBM BPM 8.5.0
Brazos Toolkit

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the Brazos UI Table component -> Configuration -> Hidden columns -> here you can specify a variable.  The value for the variable should be integer. So, depending on the value of your checkbox bound variable (true or false) you may control which column would be hidden by assigning corresponding value to the Integer variable that you use in Hidden Column configuration in a Data Table.

Also, keep in mind that the number of the first column is 0. 
If you need to specify multiple hidden columns use comma 0,2 for example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your checkbox is not a column on your table, I would recommend you wrap your table in a custom coach view, bind a local variable for hidden columns to your table and pass have another config variable variable for the checkbox value. In the load event handler, initialize the values of the comma separated hidden columns variable (`this.context.options.<checkBoxVar>.set("value",[value]`) based on checkbox value. Within the change event handler, write an event handler (`if(event.property == [checkBoxVar])`) for the checkbox change and change the value of the hidden columns appropriately.